# Help with the definition of ordinal sum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, order-theory, ordinals

"Given two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, let $A = (\alpha$ x {0}) $\cup$ $(\beta$ x {1}).

Then, define a well ordering on A by:

$(v, i) <_{A} (\tau, j) \iff (i \lt j) \lor (i = j$ $\land$ $v \lt \tau)$

Then $\alpha + \beta$  is the ordinal isomorphic to (A, $\lt_{A}$)."

I was having trouble understanding this, so I tested the definition with 2 and 3.

Let $\alpha = 2$ and let $\beta = 3$.

Since 2 = {0,1}, the ordered pairs I got from ($\alpha$ x {0}) are (0, {0}) and (1, {0}). Similarly for, 3, the ordered pairs I got from ($\beta$ x {1}) were (0, {1}), (1, {1}), and (2, {1}).

So, A = {(0, {0}), (1,{0}),  (0, {1}) , (1, {1}), (2, {1})}

Since $(A, \lt_A)$ is a woset, it is a subset of A x A.

I Got A x A to be (using [] brackets to differentiate between elements):

{

[(0, {0}), (0, {0})], [(0, {0}), (1, {0})],  [(0, {0}), (0, {1})], [(0, {0}), (1, {1})], [(0, {0}), (2, {1})],

[(1, {0}), (0, {0})], [(1, {0}), (1, {0})],  [(1, {0}), (0, {1})], [(1, {0}), (1, {1})], [(1, {0}), (2, {1})],

[(0, {1}), (0, {0})], [(0, {1}), (1, {0})],  [(0, {1}), (0, {1})], [(0, {1}), (1, {1})], [(0, {1}), (2, {1})],

[(1, {1}), (0, {0})], [(1, {1}), (1, {0})],  [(1, {1}), (0, {1})], [(1, {1}), (1, {1})], [(1, {1}), (2, {1})],

[(2, {1}), (0, {0})], [(2, {1}), (1, {0})],  [(2, {1}), (0, {1})], [(2, {1}), (1, {1})], [(2, {1}), (2, {1})]

}

Using the definition of the well ordering I got the set $(A, \lt_A)$ to be:

{

[(0, {0}), (1, {0})], [(0, {0}), (0, {1})], [(0, {0}), (1, {1})]
, [(0, {0}), (2, {1})],

[(1, {0}), (0, {1})], [(1, {0}), (0, {1})], [(1, {0}), (1, {1})], [(1, {0}), (2, {1})],

[(0, {1}, (1, {1})], [(0, {1}), (2, {1})],

[(1, {1}), (2, {1})]

}

But, if this is 2 + 3, it should intuitively have 5 elements and yet, it has 11.

Is this a correct interpretation of the definition? Did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

First, $$2\times\{0\}=\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\;,$$ not $$\{\langle 0,\{0\}\rangle,\langle 1,\{0\}\rangle\}\;.$$ Similarly,

$$3\times\{1\}=\{\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\}\;,$$

so

$$A=\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\}\;.$$

If you check the definition of $<_A$, you’ll see that I listed the elements of $A$ in increasing $<_A$-order. In fact, the set $<_A$ as a subset of $A\times A$ is

$$\begin{align*}
&\Big\{\big\langle\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 0,0\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\big\rangle,\\
&\big\langle\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\big\rangle,\\
&\big\langle\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\big\rangle,\\
&\big\langle\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\big\rangle,\big\langle\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\big\rangle,\\
&\big\langle\langle 2,1\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\big\rangle\Big\}\;.
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

There are $\binom52+5=10+5=15$ ordered pairs in $<_A$, since each pair of distinct members of $A$ must appear once (in the order $\langle\text{smaller},\text{larger}\rangle$), and each member of $A$ must appear once with itself.

Here I’m assuming that $<_A$, despite the use of $<$ instead of $\le$, is a well-order in the usual sense, which includes reflexivity. If your definition of well-order is actually of a strict well-order, so that $a\not<_A a$ for any $a\in A$, then you should delete the $5$ ordered pairs in the first column of $(1)$.

The definition really is just a way of combining $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $\beta$ follows $\alpha$. The problem is that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ aren’t disjoint, so we can’t simply move $\beta$ after $\alpha$. Instead, we make a copy, $\alpha\times\{0\}$, of $\alpha$, and a copy, $\beta\times\{1\}$, of $\beta$ in such a way that the copies are disjoint, and then we can put the copy of $\beta$ after the copy of $\alpha$.

Within $\alpha\times\{0\}$ we put $\langle \xi,0\rangle<\langle\eta,0\rangle$ if and only if $\xi<\eta$; with this ordering $\alpha\times\{0\}$ really does ‘look just like’ $\alpha$, except that each element is dragging along the label $0$. Similarly, in $\beta\times\{1\}$ we put $\langle\xi,1\rangle<\langle\eta,1\rangle$ if and only if $\xi<\eta$ in $\beta$, so that $\beta\times\{1\}$ ‘looks just like’ $\beta$ with a label $1$ glued to each element.

Then we order $A$ by ordering first on the basis of the labels, so that everything with a $0$ label (i.e., everything in $\alpha\times\{0\}$) goes before everything with a $1$ label (i.e., everything in $\beta\times\{1\}$). Within the label blocks we order according to the original $\alpha$ and $\beta$ orders. Thus, $A$ ends up ordered like this:

$$\underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{\alpha\times\{0\}}\underbrace{\Longrightarrow}_{\beta\times\{1\}}\;,$$

where the ordering with the $\longrightarrow$ is isomorphic to $\alpha$, and the ordering within the $\Longrightarrow$ is isomorphic to $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am still not understanding, though. How is $\lt_A$ isomorphic to 5? Also, why do ($\alpha$ x {0}), ($\beta$ x {1}) have to be individually ordered? Why doesn't it suffice to just order A itself?

Comment: @Julian: The whole point is to order $A$ so that it looks like a copy of $\alpha$ followed by a copy of $\beta$. If $<_A$ does this, then automatically it **must** order the copy of $\alpha$ to look just like $\alpha$, and similarly for the copy of $\beta$. The copy of $\alpha$ in $A$ is $\alpha\times\{0\}$, so $<_A$, and the easiest way to order $\alpha\times\{0\}$ to look like $\alpha$ is to order it in such a way that $\langle\xi,0\rangle<_A\langle\eta,0\rangle$ iff $\xi<\eta$ in $\alpha$. We do the same sort of thing for $\beta\times\{1\}$, the copy of $\beta$, and then make sure that ...

Comment: ... $<_A$ puts $\alpha\times\{0\}$ before $\beta\times\{1\}$.

Comment: The set $\lt_A$ does does look like $\alpha$ and $\beta$ put after another in an ordered pair form. However, I think Im still having trouble understanding the isomorphism. I derived the set (5, $\subseteq$) as a subeset of 5 x 5, since ordinals are defined by wosets. The set (5, $\subseteq$) has 15 elements, and an isomorphism can be made between the two sets. Is this how it is to be interpreted ?

Comment: @Julian: The intended order-isomorphism between $\langle A,<_A\rangle$ and $\langle 5,\in\rangle$ is the map $h:A\to 5$ that takes $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $0$, $\langle 1,0\rangle$ to $1$, $\langle 0,1\rangle$ to $2$, $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to $3$, and $\langle 2,1\rangle$ to $4$ (or its inverse).

Comment: I see. But, the definition states that $\alpha$ + $\beta$ is the ordinal isomorphic to $\langle A, \lt_A \rangle$. So, can it also be thought of as the function which maps $\langle 0, 0 \rangle, \langle 0, 0 \rangle$ to $\langle 0, 0 \rangle$ (a memebr of $\langle 5, \epsilon \rangle$ ) and so on?

Comment: @Julian: No. You seem somehow to be confusing the underlying sets, which are $A$ and $5$, with the well-orderings on them, which are $<_A$ and $\in$. In your example $\alpha=2$, $\beta=3$, and $\alpha+\beta$ is the unique ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\langle\gamma,\in\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\langle A,<_A\rangle$; this $\gamma=5$, and the isomorphism is the one that I gave above.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: @Julian: Oh, good. You're welcome.